# Displaying a specific UIViewcontroller after game center makes a match

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, game-center

I am coding in Objective C and I am able to connect to game center without issue and enter into a match just fine. But I am lost as to display my game after connected!
I have a Main menu screen with a button called multiplayer that i press that connects fine to game center and disappears fine after it connects. then i'm left at my main menu. i'd really like it to launch into the main game UIviewcontroller.

Thanks for your help and your time. I'm sure this is terribly simple for someone else who has done it before and understands the methodology. This is for real time match.

Mainmenu -> game center login/match -> gamescreen

Answer (score 0):

Ended up forgetting about using multiple view controllers and kept it all in one and just used a new view item overtop the game for the games menu. Problem solved!